# My electron app is not starting without any logging

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

So I am trying to make an electron app with angular(Typescript version) and it will not start at all, I have integrated Electron-log which does not do anything (that is the reason i think it does not start at all).

```
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const log = require('electron-log');
log.transports.file.level = 'debug';
log.transports.file.format = '{h}:{i}:{s}:{ms} {text}';
log.transports.file.file = __dirname + './log.txt';
log.transports.file.streamConfig = { flags: 'w'};
log.info('message');
// Keep a global reference of the window object, if we don't the window will be closed
// automagically when the JS object is Garbage Collected. (GC from here on out)

let win;
try {
  const createWindow = () => {
    // set timeout to render the window not until the Angular compiler is ready to show the project
    //create the browser window
    win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      icon: path.join(__dirname, 'favicon.ico'),
    });

    //and load the app
    win.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'resources/app/angular-flask/index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    }));

    // Emitted when the window is closed
    win.on('closed', () => {
      // Dereference the window object
      win = null;
    });
  };

// This method will be called when Electron has finished initialization and is ready to
// create browser windows . Some API's can only be used after this event happens.
  app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed
  app.on('windows-all-closed', () => {
    // On macOS applications might stay active untill user quits with cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit();
    }
  });


  app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS sometimes a window is recreated when the dock icon is clicked and there are no other
    // windows open
    if (win === null) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
} catch(e) {

  log.error(e)
}
```

Above is my Electron Production code, also available on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KppU1vtH) Can anyone explain why this might be happening and offer a solution?

EDIT: It did not work before I integrated electron-log. Also the angular front-end works when i start that through npx lite-server.

EDIT2: Here is my [Package.json](https://pastebin.com/mktmziQ0) and my updated main.js code [electron.prod.js](https://pastebin.com/vXvN6shU) Also I am using electron packager.

Comment: Did it work before you integrated 'electron-log'?

Comment: No i did not work before integrating that @Kyle

Comment: We need more to go off. package.json would at least help. Start with `webPreferences: { devTools: true }` in the BrowserWindow and `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();` when the app is ready. Check the console for issues with the assets (index.html) you are loading. I know it's frustrating. I just had a similar issue on Mac where it would work, but fail to load the assets after it was signed with electron-builder.

Comment: @narmageddon I added what you said but when i click the exe there isn't even a window popping up. Also i updated the question with a package.json and the updated code

Comment: @Deathshiver OK, I can get it to an index page at `resources/app/angular-flask/index.html`. BrowserWindow was also not defined. I had to add const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");` at the top of the file. I also changed the loadUrl to: `win.loadURL('file://${path.join(__dirname,"../resources/app/angular-flask/index.html")}');`. I've never done the `url.format` like you have, but I know the way I have it works on Mac and Windows.

Comment: @narmageddon Tried exactly how you said it and still nothing happens, no window and no program listed in Task Manager. Also don't get any logging when i try to run it in powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix my issue I went back to the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@PhilippKief/angular-desktop-apps-a9ce9e3574e8) I followed and checked the package.json that was used there and slowly added and updated everything I had into that package.json.
When it was still working I ported it to my own package.json and with that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `app` is not defined.

Can you please try adding the following lines at the beginning of your file.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
```

Comment: Just tried it, unfortunately it also did not work and I am still not getting any logging.

Comment: oops, let's try one more thing. Add `win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.show();
})` after 'loadUrl' line.

Comment: Nope, this also will not work. Does it have something to do with the Pathname at the win.loadUrl line maybe?